# Trouble with command line while working with python

Tags: python, django, windows, command-line

I am trying to follow a tutorial for django, but I can't even get it installed. I am running windows 10, and when I open the command line and try:
    `python --version` 
I get: 
    `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
I also cannot use the pip function at all.

Comment: You need to add python to your system `path`

Comment: First install python and configure environment

Comment: refer https://datascience.com.co/how-to-install-python-2-7-and-3-6-in-windows-10-add-python-path-281e7eae62a

Answer (score 0):

Add PATH to your system variables.

**Method 1:**
You can also add PATH to your system variables while you install by enable Add PATH to system variables.

**Mehtod 2:**
In Windows 10 and Windows 8

In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
Click the Advanced system settings link.
Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
Reopen Command prompt window, and run python.